# Stream media file from minio object

Tags: go, video-streaming, minio, go-fiber

I have a backend go fiber server which would serve files fetched from cloud service using minio client sdk. My goal is to achieve video file streaming with out exposing direct connection to cloud url and the video must be seekable, both forward and backward (same functionality as cloud's url). However, when I add the stream sent from the server, the video just can not be seeked or sometime only backwards seek. I tried to set the response's Content-Length, Content-Type, Content-Range, etc... and it just won't work. Notes: all behaviors happened in chrome latest stable version and not firefox or postman. Here is my code:

```
// c is the *fiber.Ctx

object, err := minioClient.GetObject(context.Background(), bucketName, fileName, minio.GetObjectOptions{})
if err != nil {
    return err
}

objInfo, err := object.Stat()
if err != nil {
    return err
}

buffer := make([]byte, objInfo.Size)
object.Read(buffer)

c.Set("Content-Length", fmt.Sprintf("%d", objInfo.Size))
c.Set("Content-Type", "video/mp4")
c.Set("Connection", "keep-alive")
c.Set("Content-Range", fmt.Sprintf("bytes 0-%d/%d", objInfo.Size, objInfo.Size))

c.Response().SetBodyStream(bytes.NewReader(buffer), int(objInfo.Size))
return nil

//c.SendStream just won't work
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution. Turn out I only need to add the Accept-Ranges header lol.

Answer (score 0):

In your example you don't need to read the object resulting from the GetObject of Minio to put it in a buffer only to create another Reader ... you can use the object it's already a Stream ...

Here's another suggestion using `sendStream`:

```golang
func (api *MyRoute) GetObject(c *fiber.Ctx) error {
    bucketName := c.Params("bucket", "")
    objectName := c.Params("name", "")
    
    //YOU SHOULD INTIALIZE YOUR MINIO CLIENT HERE 

    o, err := minioClient.GetObject(bucketName, objectName, minio.GetObjectOptions{})
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    stats, err := o.Stat()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    return c.SendStream(o, int(stats.Size))
}
```